# Spring configuration unable to expand property

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to enabled or disabled authorization through property file. But following is not working

`<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="${enabled}" />`

Failing xml validation

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '${enabled}' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[disabled, enabled]'. It must be a value from the 
     enumeration.

Can some one suggest me correct way of doing this ?

Comment: Did you define a context:property-placeholder bean?

Comment: @DonBottstein Yes I did that on my eclipse, it's failing with xml validation. Caused by: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 130; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '${enabled:enabled}' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[disabled, enabled]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Spring Security XSDs hard-code the possible values for that (and other) attributes IIRC:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="global-method-security.attlist">
  <xs:attribute name="pre-post-annotations">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Specifies whether the use of Spring Security's pre and post invocation annotations
        (@PreFilter, @PreAuthorize, @PostFilter, @PostAuthorize) should be enabled for this
        application context. Defaults to "disabled".
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="disabled"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="enabled"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
...
```

So property replacement is not possible if you want XML validation to succeed (because XML validation has no knowledge of Spring's replacement tokens).

Comment: So maybe Spring [profiles](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml) would be an option.

Comment: @don-bottstein thanks for the link to Spring profiles; I haven't worked a lot with Spring for the past few years. mayank-gupta

Comment: @mayank-gupta, you should give profiles a shot, it looks like it would fit the bill as long as you don't have too many different combinations of properties to support.